# How to implement a plus/minus button in a calculator work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I want to create a button on the calculator that could convert a positive number into a negative one and also could change a negative number into a positive number.

Here is the code in js:

```
function reverse_num(){
    var num = $( "#p").text();
    if(num > 0){
        $("p").prepend("-");
    }
    else if(num = 0)
    {
        $("p");
    }
}
```

When I want to convert a positive into a negative, it works fine. But I have no idea what to do when I want to remove that negative sign.

Could someone show me how to do?

Comment: `else if(num = 0)` assigns 0 to `num`. You want `else if(num == 0)` or `else if(num === 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this by two way

`Way 1`: You can remove `"-"` by using `replace('-', '')`;

`Way 2` :  You can also use `multiplication` by `(-1)`

```js
function reverse_num(){
    var num = $( "#p").text();
 if(num > 0){    
       $("p").prepend("-");
 }
 else if(num < 0){
        var num = $( "#p").text().replace('-', '');
  $("#p").text(num);
 }
 else if(num == 0){
    $("#p");
 } 
}

reverse_num();

function reverse_num_version_2(){
    var num = $( "#number").text();
 if(num > 0){    
       $("#number").prepend("-");
 }
 else if(num < 0){
        num = num * (-1);
  $("#number").text(num);
 }
 else if(num == 0){
    $("#number");
 } 
}
reverse_num_version_2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p">-100</p>

<div id="number">-100</div>
```

Comment: This is a very bad way to accomplish the task. Your code is doing so much extra work. `.replace()` is a string function, and the OP is building a calculator...

Comment: Might be its not best approach but I want to help @Vinny Mannello

Answer (score 1):

You should use basic math and multiply by -1 when the minus sign is clicked.

e.g.:

```
//Get the number
var number = parseFloat( $( "#p").text() );

//Reverse it
function reverse_num(num) {
    return (-num); // == (-1 * num)
}

//Replace the content of #p
$("#p").text( reverse_num(number) );
```

As a "oneliner"

```
$("#p").text(-(parseFloat($("#p").text())));
```

Comment: Or putting "-" before the number would suffice like: `number = -number`

Comment: Indeed, I guess I was trying to show the flow... But updated none the less.

Comment: Thanks for your advice~I could use JQery method text() to get the original number and to reverse it, but how could I set this number to the content of the p?